# Dynamically create decorator chain

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, decorator

I have a decorator chain that looks like this when initially created:

```
IType calculator = new TypeADecorator(
                            new TypeBDecorator(
                                    new TypeCDecorator(
                                        new MyCalculator())));
```

Each of these decorators does a database look up to get a piece of data which is used in a calculation

However, not all of these decorators will be used each time. Therefore, there will potentially be redundant database calls that return nothing

So I am thinking it would better to dynamically create the decorator chain based on which ones do get used

e.g.

If I had a bool representing each one that gets used:

```
bool useTypeA;
bool useTypeB;
bool useTypeC;
```

Would I be able to somehow dynamically construct the necessary chain?

Bear in mind that it's highly likely that other decorators will be added throughout the life of the app so I would like to come up with something that is quite flexable. Also, although there are only three decorators here, in reality there are about 8 used at the moment

Comment: can you provide more details? How do you decide on what decorators would you use?

Comment: i can work it out from various things in the current scope. That's not important though - as I say - just assume there are some bools telling you which should be used. I am interested in the mechanics of dynamically building the chain. Do I need to use Reflection/Activator - or is there a slicker way etc

Comment: I would store a Dictionary<bool,Func<Base,Base>> and just traverse that Dictionary once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the database lookups are done in the constructor of the decarators, would not they be deferred? Would it be possible to design your decorators in a way that they do the database lookup whenever they really need the value from the db?

Comment: that's a possibility. And one I did consider. - but rather than do a lookup in each decorator to see if it should be used. I think it's better to work out which are needed once ahead of time and then dynamically build the chain

Answer (score 4):

Yes, now you need to read about the [Builder Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern).

Comment: I can't quite see how that would help. Are you thinking I'd have a different concrete implementation of an abstract builder for each combination of decorators? That would be a lot of builders given the chain is currently about 8 long and likely to grow. Would you mind elaborating a bit?

Answer (score 0):

The part that is a bit tricky is just because youu are using your constructor to decorate (wrap/attach to) the inner object.  If you had a Decorate(IType inner) method then this simple code could be used:

```
List<IType> decorators = new List<IType>();

if (useTypeA)
   decorators.Add(new TypeADecorator());
if (useTypeB)
   decorators.Add(new TypeBDecorator());
if (useTypeC)
   decorators.Add(new TypeCDecorator());
if (useTypeD)
   decorators.Add(new TypeDDecorator());


IType calculator = new MyCalculator();

foreach (IType dec in decorators)
{
   calculator = dec.Decorate(calculator);
}
```

To keep the constructor-based method, use this:

```
List<Type> decoratorTypes = new List<Type>();

if (useTypeA)
   decoratorTypes.Add(typeof(TypeADecorator));
if (useTypeB)
   decoratorTypes.Add(typeof(TypeBDecorator));
if (useTypeC)
   decoratorTypes.Add(typeof(TypeCDecorator));
if (useTypeD)
   decoratorTypes.Add(typeof(TypeDDecorator));

IType calculator = new MyCalculator();

foreach (Type decType in decoratorTypes)
{
   calculator = Activator.CreateInstance(decType, calculator);
}
```

Note, if the order matters, you need to be aware of the order you add the item to the list.

Comment: Activator.CreateInstance is 10-20 times slower than a simple ctor but it does not give any benefit in that case

Comment: @Hohhi I like the `Decorate` version but the original post shows that the decorator objects require the object being deocorated to be passed into the constructor. So the Activator.CreateInstance version achieves that in a way my first sample does not.